# Error when setting up an SSRS data source

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2019, ssrs-2019

My server name is SQL1\DBNAMESQL1 and the name of the database is DBNAME. I entered the below into the connection string box where I set up the data source.

```
Data Source=SQL1\DBNAMESQL1; Initial Catalog=DBNAME
```

I also chose the option that says "without any credentials" just to keep it simple (SSRS is being set up for the first time, so taking baby steps here).

When I hit the test connection button, I get this error:

> The current action cannot be completed. The user data source credentials do not meet the requirements to run this report or shared dataset. Either the user data source credentials are not stored in the report server database, or the user data source is configured not to require credentials but the unattended execution account is not specified.

Comment: Try using a database user account for the credentials e.g. ReportUser

Comment: @aduguid yea that's what I ended up doing. I just picked the option to store some credentials into the data source and it worked